# How to adjust tooltip in google motion chart so as to avoid the overlapping with the plotted points?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

This is how I created motion chart but not able to figure out how to avoid tooltip overlapping with data points. I have tried to setting the tooltip

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Hospital Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'year');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage National Score');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Hospital Score');
            data.addColumn('string', 'State'); 
            data.addRows([
              ['ST MARYS HOSPITAL',  2009, 77,64,'IL' ],
              ['PROVENA ST. MARYS HOSPITAL',  2009, 63,58,'IL' ],
              ['ST. ANTHONY MEMORIAL',  2009, 82,62,'IL' ],
              ['PROVENA UNITE SAMARITAN MEDICAL CENTER',  2009, 85,63,'IL' ],
              ['GOOD SAMARITAN REGIONAL HLTH CENTER',  2009, 67,61,'IL' ],
              ['ST MARYS HOSPITAL',  2012, 64,63,'IL' ],
              ['PROVENA ST. MARYS HOSPITAL',  2012,64 ,58,'IL' ],
              ['ST. ANTHONY MEMORIAL',  2012, 68,62,'IL' ],
              ['PROVENA UNITE SAMARITAN MEDICAL CENTER',  2012, 84,62,'IL' ],
              ['GOOD SAMARITAN REGIONAL HLTH CENTER',  2012, 72,68,'IL' ]  
            ]);
        var options = {
        tooltip: { isHtml: true, trigger: 'none' }   
                           };
        options['state'] = '{"nonSelectedAlpha":0,"yZoomedDataMin":11,"iconKeySettings":[{"trailStart":"2009","key":{"dim0":"ST MARYS HOSPITAL"}}],"showTrails":true,"yZoomedDataMax":14,"time":"2009","xAxisOption":"2","playDuration":15000,"yLambda":1,"yZoomedIn":false,"xZoomedDataMin":49,"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR","xZoomedDataMax":445,"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xLambda":1,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"Y"},"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByX":false,"xZoomedIn":false,"iconType":"BUBBLE","yAxisOption":"3","orderedByY":false}';

        options['width'] = 700;
        options['height'] = 400;
      var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);      }
        </script>
```

[image: tooltip]